# Deploy error using JBoss Application Server

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have problems with installation of ovirt engine on Fedora. Ovirt is open source virtualization solution. I am trying to deploy ovirt engine setup with maven2. 
I have install all prerequirements:

- Java -1.6.0
- Maven 2.2.1
- PostgreSql
- Jboss application server

Option `mvn -e clean install` is successfully deployed.

But after when I try with `mvn -e clean install -Pgwt-admin,gwt-user` I have the build failure as result. Deploy is interrupted on deployment of web admin component of ovirt engine with message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

HS:

- Host: Windows 2008 Server 64 bit (16GB RAM)
- VS: ORACLE VIRTUAL BOX
- Virtual Machine: Fedora 16 32bit (3GB RAM)

I have tried several solutions:

1. JAVA_OPTS ="-Xms128m -Xmx256 XX:MaxPermGen:128m" to "-Xms1024m -Xmx1024 XX:MaxPermGen:256m"
2. MAVEN_OPTS with same settings
3. surefire plugin in pom.xml with same settings
4. standalone.conf in jboss folder with same settings
5. with htop memory statistics tool  when deploy is in progress memory taken by jboss process is max to 25% of whole memory (3GB).Virtual memory is 50%.

What can be done to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Oliver - You may want to check the free memory available on the system prior to starting Jboss. "free -m" will give you the amount of free system memory.